# COUNTIF/COUNTIFS workaround to calculate a number of positive cell-pairs in a line

Tags: excel

I've got the following task:

Given 16 columns with stock and 16 columns with sales, each of which represents a week (**|Stock1...Stock16|Sales1...Sales16**), basically, 16 pairs of Week_num_stock/sales.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpFVs.png

I have to calculate the number of weeks, when stock or sales or both were positive (**Stock>0/Sales=0** | **Stock=0/Sales>0** | **Stock>0/Sales>0**), in other words, a number of pairs Stock-Sales that are positive with the possible maximum of 16 (as it is the number of weeks given).

The problem I am stuck with is: if I use **countif**, it just calculates the number of positive cells, and **Stock>0/Sales>0** counts as two positive cells and in the end, I get the wrong results. And I struggle to find a workaround for that.

Hope you guys can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
= COUNITFS(A2:P2,">=0",Q2:AF2,">=0")-COUNTIFS(A2:P2,0,Q2:AF2,0)
```

Comment: Naah, it returns 16, because of >=0 (counts both 0 and 1 in both ranges).

Comment: Seems to work at least for the line on my screenshot, let me try to spread it and check if it is a universal solution (looks like one, though), thanks!

Comment: @OlegBarbasov Great! Please mark my answer as correct by placing a checkmark to it.

Comment: Aw, sure. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:P2+Q2:AF2>0)+0)`

Comment: This one seems to work as well, thanks! I'll keep both solutions in mind.